# How do I animate the simultaneous rotation and scaling of a view?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, ipad

I have this view and I do some rotation transformation to it using something like

```
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90));
//The view was originally at 0 degrees.
```

at some other point of my code, I would like to scale the view animating it, so I do

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
myViews.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0f, 2.0f);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

but when I do that the animation is performed as the view is at 0 degrees, ignoring the previous transformation. It simply assumes as the view is yet at zero degrees, so, this animation scales the view and rotates it back to 0 degrees (!!!!?????)

Is this some bug or am I missing something?
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After discussing with KennyTM, I arrived at the best solutions for having both absolute transformations...

on the zoom method, I do:

```
// notice that both transformations are absolute
CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(viewAngle));
CGAffineTransform zoom = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor);
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(rotation, zoom);
```

I store viewAngle when I rotate the view.

Answer (score 2):

Because `.transform` assignment doesn't imply the new one will be concatenated to the old one. In your new transform, you only specifies a 200% scaling, but no rotations, so the view will return to 0°.

Try this instead:

```
myViews.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(myViews.transform, 2.0f, 2.0f);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solves the rotation problem but creates the scale problem. The problem is this: I have 4 zooms factors I use for this view, something like 0.66, 1.0, 1.5 and 2.0. These are absolute values. If I use your solution it will be impossible to return back to each zoom factor....

Comment: @Mike: Why can't you use an independent ivar to store the zoom factor?

Comment: What I mean is this: suppose the zoom factor is at 1. then I use your solution and go to 0.66. Now I want to go to 2. Using the absolute scale, I just put the zoomFactor as 2, but now the zoom factor will have to be 3.03. To go back to 0.66 now, I will have to make it 0.21. After zillions of transformations I will not know what is the zoom factor now. I will have to keep a history of all applied transformations to know the current zoom factor, just looking at the ivar.... there's no way to apply the transformation to a view and make it permanent? I mean, to update the transformation matrix?

Comment: @Mike: So store the original transform, and call `CGAffineTransformScale(original_transform, 2.0f, 2.0f);`. The 1st argument of CGAffineTransformScale can take any CGAffineTransform.

Comment: If I do that, I will have the original rotation problem back. Remember that the original transform represents the view before the rotation I did (see my question). BTW, the rotation needs to be absolute too.

Comment: @Mike: What I mean is `CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90)), 2, 2);`.

Comment: sorry, but this will not solve too, because you are using relative scale and all the problems I mentioned will appear. I have discovered the best solution and posted as answer. +1 for the effort! :-)

Comment: @Mike: The end result of your solution should be the same as what Kenny suggested, given that CGAffineTransformScale concatenates the scale transform and the rotation transform you passed in (unless I have the order of the concatenation wrong).

Comment: not true, if you look my answer you will see both my transforms are absolute, not relative. Kenny's solution is an absolute rotation inside a relative translation.